# What should I do in case of error 443 ssl connection?

Tags: python, vk

I have this code:

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
import config

bot = Bot(token=config.token)

@bot.on.message(text="hello")
async def hi_handler(message: Message):
    users_info = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer("Hello, {}".format(users_info[0].first_name))

bot.run_forever()
```

I run it locally, but I get an error of this type:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host api.vk.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)')]
INFO:vkbottle:Keyboard Interrupt.
```

I tried to change api keys and also just wait, but it didn't help